# Is valid this assumption about the norm of a complex number?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

The statement was the following:

For $z,w\in\mathbb{C}$ prove that:

$$|z+w|\geq\frac{1}{2}\left(|z|+|w|\right)\left|\frac{z}{|z|}+\frac{w}{|w|}\right|$$

My attempt:

$\frac{1}{2}\left(|z|+|w|\right)\left|\frac{z}{|z|}+\frac{w}{|w|}\right|\leq\frac{1}{2}\left(|z|+|w|\right)\left(\left|\frac{z}{|z|}\right|+\left|\frac{w}{|w|}\right|\right)$

The tricky step comes when I ''asume'' (with a vector point of view) that $\left|\frac{z}{|z|}\right|=1$ for $z\neq 0$ ie is a unit vector, therefore I get:
$\frac{1}{2}\left(|z|+|w|\right)\left|\frac{z}{|z|}+\frac{w}{|w|}\right|\leq\frac{1}{2}\left(|z|+|w|\right)\left(\left|\frac{z}{|z|}\right|+\left|\frac{w}{|w|}\right|\right)=\frac{1}{2}(|z|+|w|)(2)=|z|+|w|$, therefore:
$$\frac{1}{2}\left(|z|+|w|\right)\left|\frac{z}{|z|}+\frac{w}{|w|}\right|\leq|z|+|w|$$

by inequality triangle: $|z|+|w|\geq|z+w|\quad\Rightarrow$
$$\frac{1}{2}\left(|z|+|w|\right)\left|\frac{z}{|z|}+\frac{w}{|w|}\right|\leq|z+w|\leq|z|+|w|$$

its that right? its the way?

Comment: The last ste is completely wrong.  $6 \le 8$ and $7 \le 8$ but that does not follow that then $7 \le 6$.

Comment: yes, i note that mistake later. thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

Your argument doesn’t quite work, because if $C \le |z| + |w|$ and $|z+w| \le |z| + |w|$, then you can’t necessarily conclude that $C \le |z+w|$. (You only know that both of those terms are smaller than $|z| + |w|$. You don’t know whether $C$ is bigger or smaller than $|z+w|$.)

The step $$\frac{1}{2}\left(|z|+|w|\right)\left|\frac{z}{|z|}+\frac{w}{|w|}\right|\leq\frac{1}{2}\left(|z|+|w|\right)\left(\left|\frac{z}{|z|}\right|+\left|\frac{w}{|w|}\right|\right)$$ gives away too much. We need to keep the bound tighter, so let’s avoid using the triangle inequality at first.

What about the following?
$$\frac{1}{2}\left(|z|+|w|\right)\left|\frac{z}{|z|}+\frac{w}{|w|}\right| = \frac{1}{2}\left|\left(|z|+|w|\right)\left(\frac{z}{|z|}+\frac{w}{|w|}\right)\right|$$

Expanding the product inside the absolute values gives:
$$= \frac{1}{2}\left|z + |z| \frac{w}{|w|} +|w|\frac{z}{|z|}+ w\right|$$

The goal is to keep normal (not absolute-valued) $(z+w)$’s on the inside, without going all the way to $|z| + |w|$ like the initial attempt did.

Applying the triangle inequality to the outer and inner groups of terms, we get:
$$\le \frac{1}{2}\left(|z + w| + \left||z| \frac{w}{|w|} +|w|\frac{z}{|z|}\right|\right)$$

To finish, it suffices to show that
$$\left||z| \frac{w}{|w|} +|w|\frac{z}{|z|}\right| = |z+w|,$$ which would make the right-hand side of the above inequality into a $|z+w|$ like we want.

The equation in the previous paragraph is worth picturing. Let $z = r_1 e^{i\theta_1}$ and $w = r_2 e^{i\theta_2}$. It’s basically saying that the size $|z+w|$ of the sum is unchanged if you swap their $\theta$’s.

Try to finish from here! I can help with the ending later, but I’m tired of typing this out on my phone. Haha.

Comment: Why does the first equality Is true?

Comment: is because |z| is a real number? thats the argument for the equality holds?

Comment: If $c \ge 0$, then $c|z| = |cz|$.  We're just applying that principle to the positive number $c = |z| + |w|$.

Comment: I think my recommendation for checking the equality $\left||z| \frac{w}{|w|} +|w|\frac{z}{|z|}\right| = |z+w|$ is to actually check $\left||z| \frac{w}{|w|} +|w|\frac{z}{|z|}\right|^2 = |z+w|^2$ by expanding both sides, using the fact/strategy that $|z|^2 = z \bar{z}$.  It should work out either with the original $z,w$ or with the $r_1e^{i\theta_1}, r_2e^{i\theta_2}$ forms.

Answer (score 2):

I guess we need the extra hypothesis that nor $z$ nor $w$ are zero.
I've got a kind of visual proof of that, which I made when I took the Complex Analysis course, the construction is fully geometry. I'll post a photograph of my notebook, it's easier to read all the notes on it.

[image]

The explanation is that we have two rombus. The smaller one is formed by two vectors ($\frac{w}{|w|}$ and $\frac{z}{|z|}$), and has a diagonal $\frac{w}{|w|}+\frac{z}{|z|}$. The bigger one is the result of applying a homothety with reason $(|w|+|z|)$ to the first one. Then, the sides of this rombus are the vectors $\frac{w}{|w|}(|w|+|z|)$ and $\frac{z}{|z|}(|w|+|z|)$, and has a diagonal with lenght $\left| \frac{w}{|w|}+\frac{z}{|z|}\right| (|w|+|z|)$.

After that, we draw two equal paralelograms and two rombus (green sides are all equal, orange sides are al equal). If you see the paralelograms, they have a diagonal with lenght $|w+z|$, then by triangular inequality in $XPQ$ we can conclude

$XP+PQ \geq XQ$

$|w+z|+|w+z|\geq \left| \frac{w}{|w|}+\frac{z}{|z|}\right| (|w|+|z|)$

$2|w+z|\geq \left| \frac{w}{|w|}+\frac{z}{|z|}\right| (|w|+|z|)$

$|w+z|\geq \frac{1}{2} \left| \frac{w}{|w|}+\frac{z}{|z|}\right| (|w|+|z|)$

Which is the desired inequality.